# Can't open site other than on the port 80

Tags: networking, port, windows-firewall

I installed on my server, a Bug tracker which is accessible through port 3000 `(http://myserver:3000)`.

Every thing is ok on my server, i can access to my web application any time, but in my job's computer, i cannot even connect to this application and no other web application which run on different port other than 80.

I have added a role on the windows Firewall settings by letting connection to and from port 3000. But same result.

If some one have a solution to this, i'll be thankful.

Best Regards

Comment: Do you have an antivirus solution installed that includes a firewall (most do these days)? You might have to make the rule change there instead of in Windows Firewall.

Comment: I have symantec installed but i'am not sure

Comment: I did not find no port configurations on the Antivirus parameters

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your work network is blocking your home machine.  Can you ping your home machine or access it with its ip address?  When you type

```
http://myserver:3000
```

are you doing this from the local intranet?  If you have your bug server on your home machine then you won't be able to access

```
http://myserver:3000
```

from your work machine without a fully qualified domain nae or ip address?

If the above answers are all resolved then whenever I have such difficulties on windows, I do the following.  If you don't have admin rights you might not be able to do this.

temporarily disable all firewall/antivirus programs.
Start web server listening on port 80 (on your home machine)
Access from a different machine if this works then
Start web server on 3000
Access from a different machine.

If it works then it is a matter of finding whether the problem was that the web request was being blocked by the firewall or antivirus.  In your case it appears it might be the antivirus.  To confirm disable all antivirus for a moment.

Make sure you turn your antivirus/firewall back on once the problem is diagnosed!